# Strange "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts"

Tags: paypal, checkout

I watched all the answers already present purpose they do not respond to my problem. I spent several days and really I do not understand.

I use NVP method and i try to a very simple test SetExpressCheckout Configuration like this :

```
    $param = array('METHOD'=>'SetExpressCheckout'
        , 'VERSION' =>74.0
        , 'USER' => $user
        , 'SIGNATURE' => $signature
        , 'PWD' => $password
        , 'RETURNURL' => 'http://localhost/paypaltest/index.html'
        , 'CANCELURL' => 'http://localhost/paypaltest/cancel.html'
        , 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 83.00
        , 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR'
        , 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => 10.00
        , 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEAMT' => 73.00
        );
```

normally **AMT** = **ITEAMT** + **SHIPPINGAMT** ??
I try with 1 or two decimal but i have the same "Failure" error.
What is strange is that if **I remove SHIPPING AMT**, it works and my total equals 83 on sandbox.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

SHIPPINGAMT field have been deprecated since version 63 use PAYMENTREQUEST_ n_SHIPPINGAMT instead. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks Anil. know that. In my example i use "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT" (that's why i don't understand!). I misspoke. if I remove the line "'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => 10.00", it works.

Comment: array (size=9)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2016-01-23T18:47:05Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string 'b4006fc53dc87' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '74' (length=2)
  'BUILD' => string '18308778' (length=8)
  'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10413' (length=5)
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.' (length=94)
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.' (length=63)
  'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => string 'Error' (length=5)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I had forgotten an "M" for "PAYMENTREQUEST_0 ITE**M**AMT". I put "ITEAMT" while it takes ITE**M**AMT. Paypal The answer is not pertinante. It should have an error "XXXXX_ITEAMT" not exist or something like that. I hope that this might help some of you.